# Double click on Excel file systematically shows the "Open with" dialog

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2016

On a customer's Windows 7 machine Office 2016 is apparently installed correctly. At least Word, Excel and Powerpoint run perfectly fine.

But there is one thing that doesn't work correctly:

If you double click on an Excel file, Windows won't open the file in Excel but it displays the standard "Open with" dialog where you should choose the program to open the file. Under "Recommended Programs" there is only one entry, that is Excel 2016. The "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" is checked. Now if you click on "OK", the file is opened correctly in Excel.

Next time you click on an Excel file, the same "Open with" dialog is shown again, despite the fact that the "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" has been checked previously.

Double clicking on a Word- or on a PowerPoint file works fine.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on ?

Comment: Use Control Panel> Default Programs to set the association.

Comment: @Moab that shows the same dialog as mentioned in my question.